# Information on Weather Derivatives

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, derivatives

I am looking for relevant information on the organization of the Weather Derivatives market. How is it organized? How information is shared? Where can we find historical database?

I am aware of the [CMEgroup ressource](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/weather/).

Comment: Not much volume on the CME, huh? http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/weather-volume.html

Answer (score 1):

Most of the information is not publicly available, nor are the data free of charge. One of the better sources is Kenny Tang's book,

> Tang, K., Ed. (2010). *Weather Risk Management: A guide for
>   corporations, hedge funds and investors*, Risk Books. ISBN-13:
>   9781904339687